# EF6 CurrentValues.SetValues changes current values to null

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-update

I am using EF6 with C# in Asp.net 4.5. I want to update existing entry with new entry. For example:

```
            Customer customer = new Customer()
            {
                Address = txtAddress.Text,
                Name = txtName.Text,
                UserName = txtUserName.Text
            };
            if(Id==0)
            {
                //INSERT
                customer.Password = MyHelper.md5(txtPassword.Text);
                customer.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.Customers.Add(customer);
            }
            else
            {
                //UPDATE
                Customer currentCustomer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
                customer.Id = Id;

               if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text))
                    customer.Password = MyHelper.md5(txtPassword.Text);

                db.Entry(currentCustomer).CurrentValues.SetValues(customer);
            }
```

It inserts new entry  and updates Address, Name, UserName properties successfully. But in update event, it changes CreatedDate and Password fields to NULL. Because I didn't specified Password and CreatedDate fields again. I want EF to skip these fields in update. But as I understand, it assumes these fields as null.

Is it a bug, or a feature of Entity Framework. So, what should I do if I want to update an entry with another entry? Do I have to specify all values again?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your process.  `customer` is an in-memory representation of a new `Customer`.  You define  `.Password` and `.CreatedDate` only when `Id==0` therefore it isn't available during your update routine.  And then your `.SetValues(customer)` declaration sets the existing `currentCustomer.Password` and `currentCustomer.CreatedDate` to null

Update your code to only update properties from `customer` that you wish to be updated in `currentCustomer`.  Like so:

```
//UPDATE
Customer currentCustomer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
currentCustomer.Address = customer.Address;
db.Customers.Update(currentCustomer);
```

For an even cleaner approach, you could revise entirely to:

```
Customer c;
if(Id == 0) {
    c = new Customer(){ 
       Password = MyHelper.md5(txtPassword.Text),
       CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
    };
}
else
   c = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);

if (c != null) {

    c = c{
        Address = txtAddress.Text,
        Name = txtName.Text,
        UserName = txtUserName.Text
    };
    if(Id != 0)
        db.Customers.Update(c);
    else
        db.Customers.Insert(c);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes, it is working and I am already using  this approach in other pages. But it is easier to specify values in curly braces { }. So, I used CurrentValues.SetValues in CustomerSave page. Is there any way to use curly braces also?

Comment: @OmerFarukKAYA There is with `new Customer()`.  I revised the answer above.  Please mark it as your answer if this helped you by clicking the check next to the answer.

Comment: how can I use braces after if (c != null). Instead of c.Address?